# How to retrieve and display image with userid

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage

i already upload the image with userid but . how to display image ? using uri, bitmap, or another method?

This how i upload image to firebaseStorage.

```
    UploadTask uploadTask = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(userUid).child("MembersUser").putBytes(bytes);
    uploadTask
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    imgprofile.setImageURI(uri);
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
```

This how i call or download image from firebaseStorage but i don't know how to display image when we call from firebaseStorage.

```
  StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("" +currentUserID).child("image/jpeg");

    final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
    storageReference.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {

            imgprofile.setImageURI();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });
```

When i setImageUri i don't know where there call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following to reconstruct the image as a Bitmap after downloading the `byte[] bytes` and then set the ImageView's bitmap to the one you just created :

```
   ....
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
         Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);
         imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
   ....
```